# How to exclude a particular class in javadoc with (Kdoc Dokka tool)

Tags: java, kotlin, javadoc, kotlin-dokka, dokka

In the regular Javadoc generation process, we can simply exclude a class or package by adding the below lines.

`exclude '**/SampleClass.java'`
`exclude '**/com/example/java**'`

**Question**: How to exclude/suppress a single Kotlin/java class with the **Dokka tool** ??

Below is the code to exclude a **package**.

Is there any option to exclude a **particular class**?

```
           perPackageOption {
                matchingRegex.set("com.example.xxx.xxx.package.*")
                suppress.set(true)
            }
```

**Dokka tool ref**: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/kotlin-doc.html

**Tool configurations:** https://kotlin.github.io/dokka/1.5.0/user_guide/gradle/usage/#configuration-options

Comment: add * @suppress in your all file which you want to exclude

Answer (score 0):

create a docstring with @suppress in it.  For example:

```
/** @suppress */
fun notDocced() {}
```

see https://kotlinlang.org/docs/kotlin-doc.html#suppress